# PyQt/ Python - Playing list of audio files with delay

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to loop over a list of numbers and play a corresponding audio file for each with a delay in between each sound, however when I do so, it only plays the last sound in the list. I am using the PyQt designer to build my application. Can anyone help? My code so far is below:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtGui, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import random


QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
app = QApplication([])

window = uic.loadUi("soundTask.ui")

numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
random.shuffle(numList)

def soundTimer():

    def playSound():
        QtMultimedia.QSound.play(f"soundFiles/{item}.wav")

    window.numberTimer = QTimer()
    window.numberTimer.setSingleShot(True)
    window.numberTimer.start(3000)
    window.numberTimer.timeout.connect(playSound)

for item in numList:
    soundTimer()

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your code.

First of all, you are getting only the last sound because in the cycle you're constantly overwriting a QTimer. Everytime that happens, the previous timer gets deleted by the Python garbage collector, and the only "surviving" one is obviously the last one.

Then, while the above issue might be easily addressed, the whole structure of your code makes it a bit "clunky", as it gives no real "control" or interaction with the instance, and any attempt to extend your code will result in making it worse.

In the following code I'm assuming that you're using a QMainWindow in your ui file, otherwise change the inherited class (QMainWindow) appropriately.

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtGui, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import random

numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
random.shuffle(numList)

# Change to the appropriate class used in Designer, like QWidget or QDialog
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('soundTask.ui', self)
        self.soundFiles = []
        for item in numList:
            self.soundFiles.append(f"soundFiles/{item}.wav")
        self.numberTimer = QTimer(singleShot=True)
        self.numberTimer.timeout.connect(self.playNext)
        self.numberTimer.start(3000)
        self.currentSound = None

    def playNext(self):
        if not self.soundFiles:
            return
        if self.currentSound and not self.currentSound.isFinished():
            # the previous sound is still playing, wait a bit longer
            self.numberTimer.start(500)
        self.currentSound = QtMultimedia.QSound(self.soundFiles.pop(0))
        self.currentSound.play()
        if self.soundFiles:
            self.numberTimer.start(3000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```